# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement,

Tags: mysql, hibernate

public void fontProperties(){

```
 Fonts fl=new Fonts();
```

Session sess=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

```
    Transaction tx1=sess.beginTransaction();        

    fl.setFont("arial");
    fl.setSize("arial1");
    fl.setStyle("arial2");
    fl.setLineheight("arial3");
    fl.setColor("arial4");
    fl.setBgcolor("arial5");
    fl.setBgimage("arial6");
    fl.setWidth("arial7");
    fl.setHeight("arial8");
    fl.setTop("arial9");
    fl.setRight("arial10");
    fl.setBottom("arial11");
    fl.setLeft("arial12");

    sess.save(fl);
         tx1.commit();
    sess.close();
```

Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'right, bottom, left, sid) values ('arial', 'arial1', 'arial2', 'arial3', 'arial4' at line 1
```

Comment: You have to spend some more time editing your question. Also tell us what you have tried to solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

`right` and `left` are [reserved MySQL keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Change the name of these columns.